# Azure Cosmos DB: 'Request rate is large' for simple count query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm using Cosmos DB with the Mongo adapter, accessing via the [Ruby mongo driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver). Currently there are about 2.5M records in the db.

When querying the total amount of records, there's no problem whatsoever:

```
2.2.5 :011 > mongo_collection.count
D, [2017-11-24T11:52:39.796716 #9792] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | XXX.documents.azure.com:10255 | admin.count | STARTED | {"count"=>"xp_events", "query"=>{}}
D, [2017-11-24T11:52:39.954645 #9792] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | XXX.documents.azure.com:10255 | admin.count | SUCCEEDED | 0.15778699999999998s
 => 2565825
```

But when I try to count the amount of records found based on a simple where, I run into the `Request rate is large` error:

```
2.2.5 :014 > mongo_collection.find(some_field: 'some_value').count
D, [2017-11-24T11:56:11.926812 #9792] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | XXX.documents.azure.com:10255 | admin.count | STARTED | {"count"=>"some_table", "query"=>{"some_field"=>"some_value"}}
D, [2017-11-24T11:56:24.629659 #9792] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | XXX.documents.azure.com:10255 | admin.count | FAILED | Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}
ActivityId: 0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/XXX/services/XXX/partitions/XXX/replicas/XXX/, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.17.101.1 (16500), Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}
```

I understand how the error works, but I don't understand how such a query can max out the RU/s (set at max value 10,000), since the field I'm querying is supposed to be indexed (automatically).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm facing same problem, it's really bad

Comment: Not really a solution, but I ended up enabling the [Aggregation Pipeline in the Preview Features page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmosdb-extends-support-for-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-unique-indexes-and-more/) in the Azure portal. That way you can re-write you query to use a group clause, which uses a lot less RU/s.

Answer (score 9):

The error is by design, it means that an application is sending request to DocumentDB service at a rate that is higher than the 'reserved throughput' level for a collection tier.

One solution, depending on the size of your request, is to retry the same request after some time. For other and more solutions check this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bigdatasupport/2015/09/02/dealing-with-requestratetoolarge-errors-in-azure-documentdb-and-testing-performance/).

Comment: *No, this is unfortunately not true*. Depending on the size of your collection, some requests will always fail because the number of RU/s's for that request is higher than your throughput.

Comment: @Marco, Yes. Other solutions are mentioned in their official documentation, which is already linked in the answer.

Comment: Kapil, thanks for responding, I've clarified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today. As others suggest, the Azure services are regulated by the price you are willing to pay. I found an easy answer that costs just a bit more money.

I logged into Azure, found the Cosmos DB item, opened the database and found the collection.  Each collection has an option for "Scale".  In there, I raised the limit for uploads from previous setting of 1,000 to the maximum of 10,000 for that one collection.  I ran the program, all documents were updated smoothly in about 5 minutes, and then in Azure I turned the limit back to 1,000.

The daily price jumped from $1.20 to $19.20 for about 10 minutes, otherwise all good.

It would take me an hour or two to decipher all of the steps to re-run uploads and another few hours to make sure the collection is correct after that.

Answer (score 1):

You must raise the limit of connections. By default it is at 1000, I left it at 3000 and it stopped failing.